# Express websockets on message get cookie info

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, websocket

I have an express web socket application.

In the `onmessage` function, I would like to access the cookies of the client that sent the message.

The reason for this is that I'm making a game and I have the user login. I need to check what to `name` cookie is so that I control the correct player.

This is what I've got so far:

```
var express = require('express');
var expressWs = require('express-ws');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser('secretkey123'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}))

expressWs = expressWs(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // stuff for logging in
})

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    // stuff for logging in
})

app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    res.clearCookie('name');
    res.redirect('/');
    // more stuff for logging in
})

app.ws('/ws', function(ws, req) {
    ws.on('open', function() {
        // how do I check when a connection is opened?
    })
    ws.on('message', function(msg) {
        // who sent the message? how do I get the cookie info to check the user who send it?
    })
    ws.on('close', function() {
        // the've disconnected
    })
})

var server = app.listen(8000, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port
})
```

Is this possible?

Also, where do I check when a websocket connection is opened?

I tried the 'open' event but it doesn't seem to be working.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out how to do it!

I forgot that the `req` argument can be accessed inside the other functions.

This means in the on message function you can just do this:

```
ws.on('message', function(msg) {
    req.cookies.username //do stuff
});
```

The connection open code can be done before you setup any of the events:

```
app.ws('/ws', function(ws, req) {
    // connection open code here
    ws.on('message', function(msg) {
        // connection message code here
    })
})
```

Comment: I am puzzled by this answer. The `req` object being referred to is the request which first opened the websocket, so I would have thought the cookies on that object are set to the values applicable then. When a message is received, will any changes that have been made to cookie values since the opening request be set on this old `req` object?

Comment: @JohnRC I'm not entirely sure but I don't think the cookies change during the websocket connection.

Comment: The cookies could be changed, for example, by javascript at the client end directly setting cookie values, or by responses from the server to xmlhttp requests from the client. These activities can happen while a websocket is open over any period of time. If you are only interested in the cookie values at the point in time that the socket was opened, then there's no problem, but you could move the values into a different variable so that you don't retain a reference to the original `req` object. That would be better for garbage collection.

Comment: yes  that works !, but its confusing. Now I want to access res object to send the custum response like res.send() in express, any clue ?

Comment: @Hacke I don't understand. Use `ws.send`